# Iframe only visible after log in

Tags: content

I have a website on WordPress and I am trying to add a Iframe on its website. I have done similar sort of thing on two other websites previously without any issue..

Here is the website in question: http://sharingspider.com/nfs/

However, this time I am facing some permission related issue. I can view the Iframe only after logging in. Permission set are 777 for uploads folder where I have my iframe uploaded. I can access Iframe URL directly (http://sharingspider.com/nfs/wp-content/uploads/slider/slider.htm)

Demo ID : temp
password: password

use the above username and password to see the issue
Could someone share any insight on why this is happening with this particular site?

thanks in advance, Aashish

Comment: This is not going to be answerable without the relevant code. WordPress login status should not effect how filesystem permissions work though.

Comment: can i give u the admin ID? I really need to make it work today.

Comment: No. I don't have to to debug your site for free. Plus, that is a very, very, very bad idea. You don't know me. I could do all kind of horrible things to your site. Never give out that information on the web. .. especially when you are talking about (what looks like) a commercial site !!!

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can imagine that happening is if the iframe is wrapped in a check to see if the user is logged in. As @s_ha_dum said, WordPress login isn't tied to directory permissions in any way, so just make sure that when the iframe is displayed in the theme it isn't inside any `is_user_logged_in()` or `current_user_can()` checks. Just a hunch. It's impossible to know for sure without code.